# Printf not working in http handler in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to write a web server using [Go-bootstrap library](https://github.com/go-bootstrap/go-bootstrap) and I have written my own handler in handler/users which is called on a post request on
localhost/app/signup. I am trying to print the json data to the terminal but fmt.Printf() prints nothing. The files are as follows:

#### In handler/users

```
func AppPostSignup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    fmt.Println("In AppPostSignup")
    data := map[string]interface{}{}
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    db := context.Get(r, "db").(*sqlx.DB)
    email := data["Email"]
    password := data["Password"]
    passwordAgain := data["PasswordAgain"]
    fmt.Printf("\ntype : %T\nData: %v", email, email)
    _, err := dal.NewUser(db).Signup(nil, email.(string), password.(string), passwordAgain.(string))
    if err != nil {
        libhttp.HandleErrorJson(w, err)
        return
    }
}
```

#### In main.go

```
router.Handle("/", MustLogin(http.HandlerFunc(handlers.GetHome))).Methods("GET")

router.HandleFunc("/signup", handlers.GetSignup).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/signup", handlers.PostSignup).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/login", handlers.GetLogin).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/login", handlers.PostLogin).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/app/signup", handlers.AppPostSignup).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/authenticate", handlers.Authenticate).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/logout", handlers.GetLogout).Methods("GET")
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "fmt.Printf() prints nothing"?

Comment: I am sorry everyone but I just found out that I have a different issue going on. When I make changes in handlers/users.go or any files in handlers/ those changes are not being reflected when I run main.go ($> go run main.go). [ For example I just removed a bracket and left a function open,' go run main.go ' doesn't show any error. ]  and That's why when I added a print statement, it is not printing anything. Any idea what is going on? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: In general don't use `go run`. Use `go build` and then run the resulting binary. `go run` does not typically follow the principal of least astonishment.

Comment: Either editing the wrong file, or the request didn't trigger the `Printf()` at all (e.g due to http method used). And, `go run` and `go build` make no difference in such case I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I just tested your code and I saw the following printed to the console:

```
In AppPostSignup
```

My guess is that you tried to test your `/app/signup` endpoint using a **GET** request, when you have it marked only as a **POST** request.

If you really want it to be a **POST** request, then you can test it with curl like so:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8888/app/signup
```

Note, that request is missing a valid body, but you will be able to see your message printed.